# Graphical glitch in UIScrollView when autorotating device

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an application which has a fullscreen UIScrollView, and within it there are seven images.  The images are also meant to be full screen, and the scroll view is set to enable pagination.

I have a method which either creates or moves the image views:

```
-(void)rebuildImageView{

    // set up images
    float screenW = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    float screenH = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    int numImgs = self.soundNames.count;

    self.mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenW * numImgs, screenH);
    for(int i=0; i<numImgs; i++){

        UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*)[self.mainScrollView viewWithTag:i+100];
        if(imageView == nil){
            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            imageView.tag = i+100;
            [self.mainScrollView addSubview:imageView];
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg",i]];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            [imageView release];
        }
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(i * screenW, 0, screenW, screenH);
    }

    // scroll to the current one
    [self.mainScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.currentSound*screenW, 0, screenW, screenH) animated:YES];
}
```

I also have this on the view controller:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        [self rebuildImageView];
    }];
}
```

This code works fine when I autorotate while image 0 is being shown, but when I'm on image 7, you can briefly see most of image 6 when rotating.  This video shows what's happening:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1O3jOcTgVP8

Is there a better method I should use to reconfigure the scroll view and images when rotating the device?

Comment: I also tried changing the call `scrollRectToVisible:` to have `animated:NO`.  Didn't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any frame changes put in the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration` method should automatically animate. So you could try removing it from the block?

Personally, I've had a lot more luck with this type of thing subclassing `UIScrollView` and putting the equivalent layout subview frame code in an override of the `layoutSubviews` method (don't forget to call super or you might end up with misplaced scroll bars).

Comment: Interesting.  Let me try that.

Comment: Hey, awesome - your suggestion about removing it from the block, plus making the scroll call set to `animate:NO`, fixed it.